# SQL query to return correct row number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This following query returns `RowNumber_ps = 101`, `RowNumber_ps` is the row count, however it should return `RowNumber_ps = 1` as I have only one row with 0 documents. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the query that `RowNumber_ps` does not return 1?

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order By ParentID) AS RowNumber_ps,
         UPPER(HostApplicationLocalData.ParentID) asParentID,
         COUNT(Document.ID) AS Documents 
     FROM 
         HostApplicationLocalData 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         Document ON HostApplicationLocalData.ID = Document.HostApplicationLocalData_ID
     WHERE 
         HostApplicationLocalData.TransactionType_ID = 1
         AND HostApplicationLocalData.Company_ID = 9000
     GROUP BY 
         HostApplicationLocalData.ParentID) q
WHERE
     Documents = '0'
```

Comment: Your row number works but your WHERE Dpcuments= '0' probably skips the first 100 rows.Move the row number outside the parentheses or the WHERE condition inside,if you move it insde it will be a HAVING

Answer (score -1):

You should place the 'WHERE' condition inside your subquery .